# How to start & stop PaaS app/instances in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, powerbi-embedded

My company has recently got EA Subscription for Microsoft Azure & we have started using the same. Now I have created a demo PaaS Power BI Embedded app which is up & running but I would like to understand how can I stop the same when I'm not working on it or it's not require. Also I would like to understand how can I start the app back after it has stop. The reason for doing it to avoid unnecessary billing.

Comment: take a look at Azure devtest labs which allows you to set quotas and auto shutdown for VM's, not sure whether it works for PAAS. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devtest-lab/. Just seen that it is a feature that they will add https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-devtest-labs/suggestions/13266306-increase-the-resource-types-which-can-be-used-insi#comments

Comment: Are you using App Service - Web Apps to host the Power BI app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like power bi embedded pricing is based on per session (and first 100 sessions per month are free) so i think you wouldn't need to stop. If no one is accessing the reports there should not be any charge. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/
There is a clause for usage in the same link (above) in-terms of usage.